# Problems with minimizing and closing windows in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, window-manager, minimize, window-decoration

I sometimes have problems if I close or minimize windows in Ubuntu 15.04.

If I want to close the window or minimize it, the system gets stuck and I can no longer click on anything. Only with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> I can minimize the window properly.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: try to update your system from terminal: `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: i did this few times but it did not help.

Comment: check out which window manager and session you use: `xprop -id $(xprop -root -notype | awk '$1=="_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK:"{print $5}') -notype -f _NET_WM_NAME 8t `    and your session 
`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with dropbox. I will test this. stopping dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of solutions, none of them worked for me. This is my personal solution that solved mine, hope this helps.

1. `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
2. Launch the tool and in the `Unity` section click `Switcher` then uncheck `Switch between minimized windows` checkbox.

***Note***: No need to disable any `OpenGL` or `Animation` option either form `compiz` or `unity`.